# Set reminder to Calendar without UIInteraction

Tags: iphone

I want to set reminder to calendar without user interface. means i have NSDate object to be set to calendar. how can it be done. i have gone through the UIEventKit framework. but it require UI interaction .

Looking for yr suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily i just wrote this code for one of the apps. Tweak it to suite your app.
And of course handle the error properly.

```
-(void)makeCalendarEntryWithTitle:(NSString *)title startDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate location:(NSString *)location
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *anEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    anEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
    anEvent.title = title;
    anEvent.startDate = startDate;
    anEvent.endDate = endDate;
    anEvent.location = location;
        //alarm before 5 minutes of the event
    anEvent.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-300],nil];

    NSError *error;
    [eventStore saveEvent:anEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error description - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Thnaks lukya ... is it possible to set the identifier for events??

Comment: not exactly, but you can check matching events. you need to create an NSPredicate object using EKEventStore's predicateForEventsWithStartDate method, and then fetch matching  events using eventsMatchingPredicate method...

Comment: i found eventIdentifier property for EKEvent. it can be use for finding the events that i have set. thanks again for quick response.

Comment: hey i'm sorry for above comment.. you can set identifiers for events.. and look up the events using those identifiers.. check the eventIdentifier property of EKEvent